# How to bind elements of a list to labels

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am looking for a nice code solution for the following problem.

I have a List which I want to bind to a couple of labels. The MyObject class only contains a few fields (strings and ints). This list contains of 3 elements. In my view I would like to have the following layout

1. Element 1
2. Element 2
3. Element 3

Where "Element 1", "Element 2" and "Element 3" is a property of the MyObject class.

Note that the view is already defined in Blend as follows (I prefer not to change the view-code, but if I have no choice ... ;) ):

```xml
<Label Content="1." RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.404" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
<Label Content="2." RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.404" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
<Label Content="3." Margin="0,0,0,1.077" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.404" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
<Label Content="Login bug startup (6 days)" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14.667" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Label Content="Setup screen exception (4 days)" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14.667" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Label Content="No users available bug (1 day)" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14.667" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

What is the best way to do this ? I am sure I can do this with some loose code, but I prefer a neat solution.

Thank you very much !!

Comment: I can make some properties for each element in the list, but I am quite sure that this is not the way to go. I am looking for a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MyObjectsList}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Element}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTempalte>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Number and Element are properties of your MyObject.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this with the view-code I showed in my initial post ? Using a listview forces me to again style and design the view...

Comment: than use should bind each label to a list by index. Follow this link: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2010/04/17/how-to-bind-to-the-index-of-a-collection-in-wpf.aspx.

Comment: I do not want to bind the index. My view already contains those labels. I just want to bind the "Element 1" value to each of the labels

Comment: According what you wrote you have a List<MyObject> typed property. It counts three elements. The MyObject class has a property what you want to display. You have 3 labels in the view and each of them refers to a MyObject from the list. The list I mentioned in my previous comment is the collection with MyObject instances in your data layer. Am I missing something?